# GRANT select on function FN_DUMP_DBLOG in SQL Server without GRANTing sysadmin

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to GRANT permission for an SQL login to access the functions fn_db_log and fn_dump_dblog but GRANTing SELECT on the function still fails with error:

```
Msg 9010, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
User does not have permission to query the virtual table, DBLog. 
Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role and the db_owner fixed database role have this permission
```

Below are the steps I followed:

```
create database duumy;
GO
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'password', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
USE [duumy]
GO
CREATE USER [test] FOR LOGIN [test]
GO
USE [duumy]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'test'
GO
USE [master]
GO
CREATE USER [test] FOR LOGIN [test]
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
CREATE USER [test] FOR LOGIN [test]
GO

use master;
GRANT SELECT ON FN_DBLOG TO test;
GRANT SELECT ON FN_DUMP_DBLOG TO test;
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO test;
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Please assist.

Comment: Both fn_dblog and fn_dump_dblog are undocumented command and there is hardly any information which says what rights are required. I believe ONLY a member of sysadmin fixed server role have permission to run it. Be [very careful](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/) when using fn_dump_dblog it creates hidden scheduler. I would not advise you to use these commands on production

Comment: You're going to need to use module signing to achieve what you'd like. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms345102(v=sql.100)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how this would be affected (if at all) by Azure SQL Database, but in general you should use [Module Signing](https://modulesigning.info/) to grant higher level permissions in the most targeted, secure manner.

You would create a stored procedure or multi-statement TVF containing the `SELECT ... FROM sys.fn_...` command. Then, you would sign the stored procedure or TVF with an Asymmetric Key or Certificate.

If you just need to make use of the `db_owner` role, then you can probably get away with an Asymmetric Key, then create a User from that Asymmetric Key, and finally add that User to the `db_owner` role.

A Certificate works in both cases. But, if you need to make use of the `sysadmin` server role, then you need a Certificate. So you would create a Certificate in the DB containing the stored procedure or TVF, sign that module, then create that same Certificate in `master` using only the public key, then create a Login from that Certificate, and finally add that Login to the `sysadmin` server role.

For details, please see the following posts:

- [Safely and Easily Use High-Level Permissions Without Granting Them to Anyone: Database-level](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/03/05/safely-and-easily-use-high-level-permissions-without-granting-them-to-anyone-database-level/)
- [Safely and Easily Use High-Level Permissions Without Granting Them to Anyone: Server-level](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/02/15/safely-and-easily-use-high-level-permissions-without-granting-them-to-anyone-server-level/)

Comment: The 2 links from your blog are very well written and helpful. Thanks !

Comment: @Solomon Rutzky Thank you for your response. The problem is it's not me who is directly issuing the "select" on fn_dump_dblog function. I am using an application called "DMS" in order to replicate data from On-prem SQL server to RDS which executes this funtion behind the scenes

Comment: So a direct way to GRANT a select on fn_dump_dblog without sysadmin would be appreciated!

Comment: And I couldn't do something like below: ADD SIGNATURE
    TO sys.fn_dump_dblog
    BY CERTIFICATE [Permission_fndumpdblog]
    WITH PASSWORD = 'Password@123';
    
    Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot alter the object 'sys.fn_dump_dblog', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: @Ramya I'm not sure that such a thing is possible to do directly. These two functions actually exist in the hidden, read-only DB `mssqlsystemresource`. I see that the error message says that being in `db_owner` should work, but I can't get that to work either. I will try a few other things and let you know if I can find a way.